# Callback for rails 4 delete_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have an UnreadEntry model and am using an `after_commit` callback to send a notification to a pusher service.  The problem is event fires just fine when adding records but when a `delete_all` is sent on the model, neither: `after_commit`, `after_destroy` are fired.

How can I add catch delete_all and add a callback to it?

```
class UnreadEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :feed
  belongs_to :entry

  after_commit :send_pusher_notification, if: PUSHER_ENABLED

  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :entry_id

  def self.create_from_owners(user, entry)
    create(user_id: user.id, feed_id: entry.feed_id, entry_id: entry.id, published: entry.published, entry_created_at: entry.created_at)
  end

  def self.sort_preference(sort)
    if sort == 'ASC'
      order("published ASC")
    else
      order("published DESC")
    end
  end

  def send_pusher_notification(user = nil, from = 'UnreadEntry#callback')
    if user.nil?
      unread_count = UnreadEntry.where(user_id: self.user_id).count
    else
      unread_count = UnreadEntry.where(user_id: user.id).count
    end
    Pusher['rssapp'].trigger('unread_count', {
      message: unread_count
    })  
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple - don't use `delete_all`.  [`delete_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete_all) and [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) are specifically designed to query the database directly, bypassing the ActiveRecord model logic - including validations and callbacks.  If you want callbacks, call `destroy` on each model instance individually.

```
my_collection.each(&:destroy)
```